# VBA User Defined Function returning strange or no results

Tags: excel, vba, highcharts, user-defined-functions

I am creating a UDF that is meant to produce a string that I can put into HighCharts.  So basically, I am inputting two ranges of data (numbers or text) into the UDF and outputting a string or formatted pairs that looks like this [[ DataX, DataY], [DataX1, DataY1], ...]

Things work fine for the first range, but the second range give me garbage results.

Here's my code:

```
Function HCP(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range) As String
' this function will take columns of data and properly format them for highcharts

Dim Str1, Str2, retVal As String
Dim leng, i, j As Integer
Dim col1, col2, row1, row2 As Long
Dim temp1, temp2 As Range

Str1 = "["
Str2 = "]"
col1 = Rng1.Column
col2 = Rng2.Column
row1 = Rng1.Row
row2 = Rng2.Row

leng = Rng1.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To leng
If i < leng Then
Set temp1 = Rng1.Cells(row1 + i - row1, col1)
Set temp2 = Rng2.Cells(row2 + i - row2, col2)

retVal = retVal & "[" & temp1 & "," & temp2 & "],"
Else
retVal = retVal & "[" & temp1 & "," & temp2 & "]"
End If

Next i
retVal = Str1 & retVal & Str2

HCP = retVal
End Function
```

I call the function using this formula: =hcp(D2:D61,O2:O61)

The results don't make sense to me. The first range of data starts one row too low.  I get several nothing values then after a while I start getting data coming from another part of the sheet in column 29. I'm guessing that it's starting with the empty cells in col 29 but I have no idea why that would be.

Here's another clue that might help get to the bottom of this. If I use the formula =hcp(A2:A61,B2:B61) the formula is grabbing data from A and C and down. Where is it adding additional columns? when I do =hcp(A2:A61,C2:C61) it is starting at A and E. When I put in =hcp(A2:A61,D2:D61) I get A and G results.

The same thing happens when I change it to this =hcp(B2:B61,C2:C61) I get C and G... you see the pattern.

I don't see how it is multiplying by 2 on my second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First tip**:

In line `Dim col1, col2, row1, row2 As Long` - only `row2` declared as `Long`, but other variables are `Variant`.

You should use `Dim col1 As Long, col2 As Long, row1 As Long, row2 As Long` instead. The same for other declarations.

**Second tip**: in line `Rng1.Cells(row1 + i - row1, col1)` - expression `row1 + i - row1` is always equals to `i`

**Third tip:** when you are using `Rng1.Cells(row1 + i - row1, col1)` it works like offset `i-1` to the bottom and `col1-1` to the right ***from top left cell of*** `Rng1`.

So for `D2:D61` range `col1` would be equals to `4` and that's means that `Rng1.Cells(1, col1)` would be `G2` (offset to the bottom `1-1` and to the right `4-1` from `D2`) and it's not what you're expecting.

Try this function instead:

```
Function HCP(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range) As String
    ' this function will take columns of data and properly format them for highcharts
    Dim retVal As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'if ranges doesn't contains one column and same rows count - return #VALUE error
    If Rng1.Rows.Count <> Rng2.Rows.Count Or _
        Rng1.Columns.Count <> 1 Or Rng2.Columns.Count <> 1 Then
        HCP = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If

    For i = 1 To Rng1.Rows.Count
        retVal = retVal & "[" & Rng1.Cells(i, 1) & "," & Rng2.Cells(i, 1) & "],"
    Next i
    'remove last comma
    If retVal <> "" Then retVal = Left(retVal, Len(retVal) - 1)

    HCP = "[" & retVal & "]"
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was very helpful. Works perfectly! Learned my lesson for sure.